# Constraint (requires) for a template template parameter

Tags: c++, constraints, c++20

How do I constrain the type T when T is not part of the functions signature?
E.g. If I want a function that works for arrays of any size.

```
template<typename T, size_t Size>
requires same_as< T, std::array<int, Size> >
auto foo( const string & str )
{
    T ret;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < Size && i < str.length(); i++ )
        ret[i] = str[i];
    return ret;
}

auto f1 = foo<std::array<int, 3>>( "123"s );
auto f2 = foo<std::array<int, 4>>( "1234"s );
```

Comment: Please post full mcve, guessing all the `#include` and `using namespace` is no fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a type trait checking whether a type is a specialization of `std::array` with the help of partial specialization and use that as a concept

```
// primary template for type trait
template<typename>
struct is_std_array : std::false_type {};

// partial specialization matching std::array specializations
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct is_std_array<std::array<T, N>> : std::true_type {};

// concept from the type trait
template<typename T>
concept std_array = is_std_array<T>::value;

// use as a concept
template<std_array T>
auto foo( const string & str ) {
    /*...*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class T>
concept std_array = requires(T a)
{
  { []<class V, std::size_t N>( std::array<V,N>& ){}(a) };
};
```

this checks if your type can be used to deduce a `std::array`'s size and type.  This will work if you are either a `std::array` or your base class is.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/jo3jEG83E).